# Trying to find a 1990s-2000s Anime revolving around the mc collecting yins and yangs

Tags: story-identification, anime

My memory is hazy but I saw this anime around 10 years ago roughly 2010. The main character collected a couple of gems that were shaped like yins and yangs of different colours and fought mech monsters, one of them was a monster train.

I distinctly remember the last episode where the main character returns to the normal world in an orange afternoon as a normal kid and other kids are playing baseball.

edit 1

I think the protagonist was a normal boy at the start but he is transported into another fantasy world, and in this world there are levels where he also goes up.

The gems were shaped like yins and yangs (separate yins and yangs, like as in the shape of a 9 or 6) and gave the main character some sort of power, and each were different colours of the rainbow.

Comment: You say he returned to the normal world, how? How did he end up in the other world in the first place? Can you remember anymore specific plot elements or episode outlines as collecting gems and killing monsters is quite a common trope. If you remember anything else you can [edit] the details into your question.

Comment: Possibly Otogi Zoshi? The first half involves collecting five different coloured magatamas, which do look like half of a yin yang symbol each.

Comment: It was more of a cartoonish anime, colourful that caught the eye and the main character was a boy.